# Saving cookies in Alamofire (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, cookies, xcode7, alamofire

I want to store my cookies so that when i reopen the application i can restore the ones stored in the previous instance.
To initialize alamofire i use:

```
let manager = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance
```

And my code to load cookies is:

```
let cookies = NSHTTPCookie.cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields(headerFields, forURL: URL)
Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session.configuration.HTTPCookieStorage?.setCookies(cookies, forURL: URL, mainDocumentURL: nil)
```

But when i reboot the phone it forgets all the cookies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1.Add method to save cookies in `NSUserDefaults`

```
func setCookie (cookie:NSHTTPCookie)
{        
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(cookie.properties, forKey: "kCookie")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}
```

2.And method to retrieve them after reboot

```
func getCookie () -> NSHTTPCookie
{
    let cookie = NSHTTPCookie(properties: NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("kCookie") as! [String : AnyObject])
    return cookie!
}
```

3.Retrieve cookies from request in Alamofire

```
let cookies = NSHTTPCookie.cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields(response.response?.allHeaderFields as! [String: String], forURL: (response.response?.URL!)!)

//Save method
setCookie(cookies.first!)
```

4.Use `getCookie` method after reboot before any request

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().setCookie(getCookie())
```

**IMORTANT NOTE:** Tested in Swift 2.2

Answer (score 20):

For Swift 3 and Alamofire 4.4

1.Add method to save cookies in `UserDefaults`

```
func saveCookies(response: DataResponse<Any>) {
    let headerFields = response.response?.allHeaderFields as! [String: String]
    let url = response.response?.url
    let cookies = HTTPCookie.cookies(withResponseHeaderFields: headerFields, for: url!)
    var cookieArray = [[HTTPCookiePropertyKey: Any]]()
    for cookie in cookies {
        cookieArray.append(cookie.properties!)
    }
    UserDefaults.standard.set(cookieArray, forKey: "savedCookies")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}
```

2.Use saveCookies() in Alamofire

```
Alamofire.request(urlString).responseJSON { response in
    saveCookies(response)
}
```

3.Add method to load cookies from UserDefaults

```
func loadCookies() {
    guard let cookieArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "savedCookies") as? [[HTTPCookiePropertyKey: Any]] else { return }
    for cookieProperties in cookieArray {
        if let cookie = HTTPCookie(properties: cookieProperties) {
            HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(cookie)
        }
    }
}
```

4.Use loadCookies() before `Alamofire.request()`